# How do I migrate from Code Review to Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, migration

I know about moving questions [from Stack Overflow to Code Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204124/can-we-move-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review), but what about the other way around? It seems like almost half the questions I come across on Code Review get put on hold or closed because they are questions about how to fix code rather than improve working code, hence would be SO questions instead of CR. When flagging these questions, I don't see an option to suggest that they get moved to SO (unlike the other way around), and when I flagged such a question for Moderator support, saying that it should be moved to SO, my flag was "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

Considering how commonly this is needed, why isn't there an easy flag option to request that a Code Review question be moved to Stack Overflow? If there is such a flag at a higher reputation level, shouldn't it be made available at lower reputation levels (I'm 400+ and don't see any such flag)?

Answer (score 5):

My mistake, I have found exactly this flag under <kbd>should be closed...</kbd> -> <kbd>off-topic because...</kbd> -> <kbd>This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network</kbd> -> <kbd>belongs on stackoverflow.com</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that **not every question about non-working code on Code Review would be a good question on Stack Overflow**.

In fact, there are very few questions, which are closed with the "non-working code"-reason, that would be good questions on Stack Overflow.

As a moderator, if I see a question that is flagged with "belongs on Stack Overflow" I ask myself: If this would be posted on Stack Overflow, would I upvote it? Do I think others would upvote it? If not, then I don't migrate it.